# Alternative for Apache Usergrid Counters

Tags: postgresql, redis, counter, usergrid

I am using Apache Usergrid for a project. However I have a serious problem with its counters. It may take to 30 seconds for a counter to be updated. So I want to use something other than usergrid counters. My question is:

Is there a structure for redis, postgresql or memcached that I will be able to use hierarchical counters. Or is there any other tool for that purpose?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such counter in `Redis`, but you can implement one with lua script.

> Hierarchical Counter

Each time you increment a counter with the name of *"first.second.third"*, it automatically increments 3 counters: *"first.second.third"*, *"first.second"*, and *"first"*.

**hierarchical counter lua scripts: hc.lua**

```
local key = KEYS[1]
while key do
    redis.call("incrby", key, ARGV[1])
    key = string.match(key, "(.+)%.")
end
```

Try it with `redis-cli`:

```
./redis-cli --eval hc.lua first.second.third , 2
(nil)
./redis-cli mget first first.second first.second.third
1) "2"
2) "2"
3) "2"
```